# Export one part of two columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two columns in an excel worksheet. One column has a list of sentences (in different languages), the other column has the a list of the corresponding language.

The columns have thousands of rows, therefore copy and paste is not an option.

I would like to export all the sentences in one column that are in English.

Comment: Copy and paste seems like the most straightforward solution.  Have you tried that?  What happened? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: tried data > filter? | then copy-paste